# Recursive multiline sed - remove beginning of file until pattern match

Tags: regex, unix, sed, substitution

I have nested subdirectories containing html files. For each of these html files I want to delete from the top of the file until the pattern `<div id="left-`
This is my attempt from osx's terminal:

```
find . -name "*.html" -exec sed "s/.*?<div id=\"left-col/<div id=\"left-col/g" '{}' \;
```

I get a lot of html output in the termainal, but no files contain the substitution or are written.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems with your command. The first problem is that you aren't selecting an output location for `sed`. The second is that your `sed` script is not doing what you want it to do: the script you posted will look at each line and delete everything ON THAT LINE before the `<div>`. Lines without the `<div>` will be unaffected. You may want to try:

```
find . -name "*.html" -exec sed -i.BAK -n "/<div id=\"left-col/,$ p" {} \;
```

This will also automatically back up your files by appending `.BAK` to the original versions. If this is undesirable, change `-i.BAK` to simply `-i`.

Comment: Thanks, jackpot, out of interest, is there a simple way of switching this to delete after, and not before?

Comment: Yes, just change the `sed` string to `"1,/yourpattern/ p"`. You can do both at the same time with `"/startpattern/,/stoppattern/ p"`.

Answer (score 1):

You're outputting the result of the `sed` regex to `stdout`, the console, when you want to be writing it to the file.

To perform find and replace with sed, use the `-i` flag:

```
find . -name "*.html" -exec sed -i "s/.*?<div id=\"left-col/<div id=\"left-col/g" '{}' \;
```

Make sure you **backup your files** before performing this command, if possible.  Otherwise you risk data-loss from a mistyped regex.

Comment: hmm, I'm getting a long list of filenames and `sed: 1: "./foo/bar ...": invalid command code .` with that

Answer (score 0):

You're not storing the output of `sed` anywhere; that's why it's spitting out the html.